# If else condition issue

Tags: javascript, html

I'm making a quiz for my website. I am checking for input on each question. The first one is simply the user's name. I got that one to work using an if else statement, what I'm trying to do now is check the radio button after the checking the textbox. So, if the user enters their name and then doesn't answer the next question an alert window pops up asking them to answer it. I'm also doing this for checkboxes and a drop down menu. Based on the color selected on the radio buttons the background of the website will change. Any help with any of the issues would be most appreciated.

**JavaScript**

```
function NameBox() {
    var x = document.forms["Hogwarts"]["firstname"].value;
    if (x == null || x == "") {
        window.alert("Name must be filled out!");
        return false;
    } else {
        RadioColors();
        return true;
    }
}

function RadioColors() {
    If(document.getElementById('red' || 'blue' || 'green' || 'yellow').checked)
    window.alert("Radio Selected");
    else {
        window.alert("Radio Not Selected");
    }
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="main">
     <h1>Assignment 2: Sorting Hat Quiz<h1>
<form name="Hogwarts" onsubmit= "return NameBox()" >

  <fieldset>

   <legend>Which Hogwarts House Are You In?</legend>

  <br>

<h1>Please Enter Your First Name</h1>

    <input type="text" name="firstname" value="">
    <br>

<h1>What is your favorite color?</h1>

    <input type="radio" name="color" value="red">Red
    <br>
    <input type="radio" name="color" value="blue">Blue
    <br>
    <input type="radio" name="color" value="green">Green
    <br>
    <input type="radio" name="color" value="yellow">Yellow
    <br>

<h1>Which of these values do you possess?</h1>

    <input type="checkbox" name="gry1" value="chivalry">Chivalry
    <br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="sly1" value="Cunning">Cunning
    <br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="huf1" value="loyalty">Loyalty
    <br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="rav1" value="intelligence">Intelligence
    <br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="gry2" value="brave">Brave
    <br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="sly2" value="innovative">Innovative
    <br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="huf2" value="patience">Patience
    <br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="rav2" value="logical">Logic
    <br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="gry3" value="confident">Confident
    <br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="sly3" value="Ambitious">Ambitious
    <br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="huf3" value="friendly">Friendly
    <br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="rav3" value="creative">Creative
    <br>

<h1>What is your favorite animal?</h1>

    <select name="animal">
        <option value="selectanimal">Select an Animal</option>
        <option value="snake">Snake</option>
        <option value="lion">Lion</option>
        <option value="raven">Raven</option>
        <option value="badger">Badger</option>
    </select>
    <br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    <br>
    <input type="reset" value="Reset">
    </fieldset>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: First, make sure you take out the uppercase "I" in your if statement -- the `if` keyword is always lowercase.

Comment: Are you using some kind of framework to correctly parse that line: If (document.getElementById('red'||'blue'||'green'||'yellow').checked) ?

Comment: I'd suggest that the very first thing you do is look in the browser error condole or debug console and fix all the script errors that will be reported there.  No code that contains obvious syntax errors should be posted here without first examining the errors yourself and attempting to fix them.  This is one of the most basic steps in developing code.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately you can't simply use the following:

```
If (document.getElementById('red'||'blue'||'green'||'yellow').checked)
```

You have to split each id in to a separate bit and it would get *very* verbose. However JavaScript is (usually) wonderfully flexible so you can reduce the amount of code so try the following:

```
function id_(id) {var r = false; if (document.getElementById(id)) {r = document.getElementById(id);} return r;}

if (id_('red').checked || id_('blue').checked || id_('green').checked || id_('yellow').checked) {}
```

You're still calling `document.getElementById` though through a proxy function which is fine because it can help keep your code much less verbose. Do **not** change the function name from **id_** to **id** though as it will create a mind-bogglingly horrible conflict when you use `id` for parameters sent to functions.

Other then that use Firebug for Firefox or any of the built in web consoles/inspectors (Chrome CTRL+SHIFT+J, IE F12 Developer tools and (real) Opera Dragonfly).

Answer (score 0):

Check how you're calling document.getElementById -

Essentially, anything in the parentheses is an input to the function, and if you have operators in that input, those will be evaluated first.

In your case you're supplying:

```
'red'||'blue'||'green'||'yellow'
```

The operators in this statement are designed to return a `Boolean` value, ie, `True` or `False`.

`'red'` is a string (as are the others), and in Javascript, any string with a length greater than zero is a "truthy" value.

Since these are evaluated before being input to getElementById, what it's actually supplied is `true`.

You can envision it being called like this:

```
document.getElementById(true)
```

And of course you have no element named "true".

Your first port of call will, then, be to structure the logic differently, as what you want to compare is whether the element with ID `'red'` is checked, OR the element with ID `'blue'` is checked, etc.

Try something like

```
if (document.getElementById('red').checked || document.getElementById('blue').checked || document.getElementById('green').checked || document.getElementById('yellow').checked )
```

This way, you're comparing the results instead of supplying a boolean as input

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `getElementById` since the radio buttons were not assigned `id`s. Instead, since each radio button was assigned the same `name` to indicate they are a part of the same radio button group, you can use `getElementsByName` to find all of them. Then iterate through them to determine which one is `checked`.

```
function RadioColors () {
    var selectedColor;
    var colors = document.getElementsByName('color');
    for (var i = 0; i < colors.length; i++) {
        if (colors[i].checked) {
            selectedColor = colors[i].value;
        }
    }

    if (selectedColor)
        window.alert("Radio Selected");
    else {
        window.alert("Radio Not Selected");
    }
}
```

Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qck1q6zn/) for you to check it out in action.